# Adding to array causes all items in array to be re-rendered

Tags: ember.js

I have an (Ember-CLI 1.13.1) array which I am looping over to display the items of that array using a component. When I add and item to that array I would expect the new item to be rendered, but the existing items to remain unchanged. However, what I am seeing is that ALL items in the array are re-rendered.

I was under the impression that only the new / changed / deleted items should result in a re-render? Otherwise, that is potentially (as is the case in my app where we are rendering hundreds of complex items using a whole host of nested components) a lot of wasted processing and rendering time resulting in slow performance and pauses for the user.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this the expected behaviour for Ember?

This simple example shows the re-rendering clearly:

**application.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    data : Ember.A([]),

    actions :
    {
        addData : function()
        {
            var data = this.get("data");

            data.addObject({label:data.length});
        },
    }
});
```

**test-component.js**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    getlabel : function()
    {
        var item = this.get("item");

        Ember.Logger.log("getlabel",item.label);

        return item.label + " " + new Date;

    }.property('item.label'),

});
```

**application.hbs**

```
<button {{action 'addData'}}>Add</button>

{{#each data as |item|}}

    {{test-component item=item}}

{{/each}}
```

**test-component.hbs**

```
{{getlabel}}
```

Each click of the button add's an object to the array, which application.bhs loops over to display the list. As you can see, the getLabel function is bound on item.label, so since this does not change as items are added, I would not expect this to be run again as items are added. However, as you will see from the logs and view the timestamp change on the screen, it is re-called and the component content re-rendered as items are added to the array.

See it in action here: http://ember-twiddle.com/a37e6128cc07fdf3a202

So, in summary:

1) Why does Ember re-render the test-component for every item in data when I add a new item to data?

2) Is there a way to prevent it doing this so only inserted / deleted / replaced items are re-rendered?

Comment: One strange thing is when i click on __add__ time on all items get changed which is causing all items to re-render. But I don't know why all times are changing.

Comment: The time change is not causing the re-render, it's just a symptom of it. The time is not part of the data, so cannot be updated. I'm just using it to visualise the fact that the re-render has taken place. It is very odd behaviour and not what I'd expect. I'm wondering if this is something recently broken in Ember as I can't imagine no one else would have spotted this before it's it had been this way all along.

Comment: On closer inspection I can see that the test-component's DIV is NOT re-rendered when items are added to the array. But, the getLabel function is called for every item in the array. So I guess the question is why is that fired for the old items and not just for the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a related question here: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/computed-properties-used-inside-each/8578/4

It seems that this is an Ember bug and was resolved in 1.13.7. The latest Ember-CLI uses Ember v.1.13.3, so it'll take  a manual update to fix this for now.